# ASP.NET Sort gridview using tableSort

Tags: jquery, asp.net, tablesorter

I have an ASP.NET web application where I pull some data from a database and bind it to a gridview upon a users dropdownlist selection.
The gridview contains (among others), a checkbox column.
I want to implement gridview sorting but the problem with using AllowSorting and OnSorting is that it postbacks and I lose the checkbox selections.

So I decided to look into client side sorting and I jquery tableSort. 
I'm trying to implement it but it doesn't sort anything.

I added in the header prerequisites that point to the jquery scripts

Now I need to add

```
$(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $("#myTable").tablesorter(); 
    } 
);
```

I have done that (replacing myTable with my gridview id) and it's not sorting anything. Could it be because I'm not binding the data in PageLoad ? I'm doing it in another function because I'm waiting for a user selection.

Then I found out it needs to render the THEAD and TBODY.
So I added the following just after binding the data to the gridview:

onlineSearchGridView.UseAccessibleHeader = true;//I read that this is true by default and don't really need it
onlineSearchGridView.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;

Having said all this, what could I do to make the gridview sort ? 
I don't understand how does the tablesort know when I click on a header column ? 
There is no link or button or anything. How is the event being detected?
My guess is that it's not sorting because the function where I specify tablesorter is not being reached, or it's being called too early before there is any header in the gridview ?

Update:

This is my gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="OnlineSearchGridView" runat="server" Visible="false" AutoGenerateColumns="true" OnRowDataBound="OnlineSearchGridView_RowDataBound" Height="50px" CellPadding="5" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="9pt">
```

This is my tablesort function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("OnlineSearchGridView").tablesorter({debug: true});
```

});

Do I need to put the # before my table id ?

This gridview is inside a login view. Could that be a problem?
I noticed that when the table gets rendered it has an id like LoginView1_OnlineSearchGrid. Do I need to change the id in the tablesort function? 
If all of these are correct and it is still not working, I'm thinking it's because the document.ready function is called when the page loads and I'm binding the data in the datatable after a certain user selection.
Should I change that to just function tblSort() or something, and call that in an OnChanged event for that dropdownlist ?

Comment: Tablesorter binds to the click event within a header cell. You can troubleshoot why it isn't working by turning on the debugger... `$("#myTable").tablesorter({ debug: true })` as an option, then look in the console (Press F12 and click the console tab)

Comment: I have enabled debug but nothing shows up.

Comment: Did you try setting [`EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks="false"`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.enablesortingandpagingcallbacks(v=vs.110).aspx) on GridView before moving to client side solution?

Comment: Haven't found anywhere that I need to add this. I have added it and nothing changed. I know I'm doing something wrong but I don't know where :(

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this. It was actually simple but I haven't used jQuery before. The way I solved this is using the following:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("table").tablesorter();
    });
</script>
```

So I have to use "table" instead of the gridview id. I found [this article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/sorting-in-gridview-using-tablesorterjs-in-asp-net) to be helpful.

Now I need to worry about customizing and styling the entire thing, but at least it's sorting so I'm happy.